# A database on Maass forms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, maass-forms, online-resources

Is there somewhere a database on Maass forms that includes eigenvalues, Taylor coefficients, etc...?

I am mainly interested in classical forms on $\Gamma(1)\backslash H$.

Comment: http://www2.math.uu.se/~astrombe/emaass/emaass.html

Comment: Thank you! This is good. But actually I would like to have more forms, even if less accurate.

Comment: http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/Maass/

Comment: I only see eigenvalues there.

Comment: Oh yes! I found the coefficients! Thank you much!

Comment: Admittedly, it is not very convenient to copy and paste all this. Maybe, there are files?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, the only big online database of Maass forms is that at [**LMFDB**](http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/Maass/), with the data of 16599 forms so far.

In order to get the data on a more convenient format, you can go from the page of the Maass form ([example](http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/Maass/4cb8503a58bca91458000003)) to the one of the associated L-function ([example](http://www.lmfdb.org/L/ModularForm/GL2/Q/Maass/4cb8503a58bca91458000003/)). There's a link from one page to the other at the right, "Related objects" -> "L-function". In the page of the L-function you can download a file with the coefficients and such ([example](http://www.lmfdb.org/L/ModularForm/GL2/Q/Maass/4cb8503a58bca91458000003/?download=lcalcfile)), that's avaible in "Downloads" -> "Lcalcfile".